# Greatest common divisor questions?

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

An integer d is a *divisor* of *a* ⇔ ____ | ____.

Equivalently, d is a *divisor* of *a* ⇔ ____ mod ____ = _____.

 Is it possible for a divisor of *a* to be bigger than *a*?

The first blank would be d|a, and I am not sure about the second. 
And for the third question, I believe so. But I am not sure how to explain why.

Comment: Sure, $2$ is a divisor of $-18$. Also, $17$ is a divisor of $0$. But if we restrict to positive integers, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ mod $d$ = 0 <=> $d | a$.

Divisor of $a$ can not be bigger than $a$, because $d | a$ <=> $a = c * d$. If $d > a$, $c < 1$, and it is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

$d$ is a divisor of $a$ if $a/d$ is whole, in other words if $a \pmod d = 0$.

If $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $d>a$, what does $a/d$ look like?

Answer (score 2):

think `mod` operator as the remainder.  If d divides a, the remainder should be zero by definition.  Also think what will be the maximum divisor of an integer number?

Answer (score 1):

1. $d|a$
2. $a=0 \mod d$
3. It depends. If we are talking about positive integers then no, but for rationals or reals it is possible.